# cURL to Postman - Copying code to Python gives EOL error

Tags: python, api, postman

With Postman I've successfully created a cURL request and Postman converted this request to Python. If I copy paste my code it's giving me **SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal**

Code I received from Postman :

```
import requests

url = "curl \"https://nl-sports.unibet.be/sportsbook-feeds/views/filter/football/belgium/jupiler_pro_league/all/matches?includeParticipants=true&useCombined=true&ncid=1643034406\" ^
  -H \"authority: nl-sports.unibet.be\" ^
  -H \"sec-ch-ua: ^\\^\" Not;A Brand^\\^\";v=^\\^\"99^\\^\", ^\\^\"Google Chrome^\\^\";v=^\\^\"97^\\^\", ^\\^\"Chromium^\\^\";v=^\\^\"97^\\^\"\" ^
  -H \"sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\" ^
  -H \"user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36\" ^
  -H \"sec-ch-ua-platform: ^\\^\"Windows^\\^\"\" ^
  -H \"accept: */*\" ^
  -H \"sec-fetch-site: same-origin\" ^
  -H \"sec-fetch-mode: cors\" ^
  -H \"sec-fetch-dest: empty\" ^
  -H \"referer: https://nl-sports.unibet.be/betting/sports/filter/football/belgium/jupiler_pro_league/all/matches\" ^
  -H \"accept-language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7\" ^
  -H \"cookie: optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1635946454400r0.8064275294347107; cms_affref=^\\^\"https://unibet.be/^\\^\"; affref=^\\^\"https://unibet.be/^\\^\"; _ga=GA1.3.2044171515.1635946455; CookieConsent=^{stamp:^%^274QIdzIsIItjHalOpIhHsBhtQ3RZ6ykPoeqbeM1OdvKGyxG4d/KQ8AQ==^%^27^%^2Cnecessary:true^%^2Cpreferences:true^%^2Cstatistics:true^%^2Cmarketing:true^%^2Cver:1^%^2Cutc:1636917812628^%^2Cregion:^%^27be^%^27^}; isReturningUser=true; _kbcexp=^{^\\^\"experimentId^\\^\":^\\^\"DoCPhfVUQgKLbmsfJ_VPyQ^\\^\",^\\^\"variationId^\\^\":1^}; DTMhasEverLoggedIn=1; _gcl_au=1.1.1282485291.1636919063; home_market=https://nl.unibet.be; clientId=polopoly_desktop; __utmt=1; __utma=186947575.441334896.1643034379.1643034379.1643034379.1; __utmb=186947575.1.9.1643034379; __utmc=186947575; __utmz=186947575.1640463878.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)^|utmccn=(direct)^|utmcmd=(none); AMCVS_F431E3BC5593E3887F000101^%^40AdobeOrg=1; AMCV_F431E3BC5593E3887F000101^%^40AdobeOrg=359503849^%^7CMCIDTS^%^7C19017^%^7CMCMID^%^7C67643106713851798281164191083147300093^%^7CMCAAMLH-1643639180^%^7C6^%^7CMCAAMB-1643639180^%^7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y^%^7CMCOPTOUT-1643041580s^%^7CNONE^%^7CMCAID^%^7C307AE6471406DA2D-4000119A8E36CC44^%^7CvVersion^%^7C5.0.1^%^7CMCCIDH^%^7C-1724411699; INGRESSCOOKIE_APIGATEWAY=3f6138fb645031d118e6234403391d10; cms_tomcat=842030dd6e28d1ec005c2079edf9f61f; INGRESSCOOKIE_CMS=49c81bc961e4a54798de87010667a06b; USESSIONID=3095C9FA2DF0312889D972B174778128; campaignIdByLobby=2379996; _gid=GA1.3.767128848.1643034385; trackingQuickAccess=; currentVidDisplay=; _uetsid=997d84d07d2111ecab68afaa496294aa; _uetvid=bd833ac03caa11ec8b4cc721bad18248; _clck=1f2buim^|1^|eye^|0; sbppn=:betting:sports:football:belgium:jupiler_pro_league; sbppt=event^%^20list~; s_nr=1643034386846-Repeat; _clsk=1xsvql^|1643034387927^|3^|1^|e.clarity.ms/collect; utag_main=v_id:017ce601df9f0014c6961521a19605072001206a00bd0^$_sn:66^$_se:5^$_ss:0^$_st:1643036204913^$vapi_domain:unibet.be^$adform:9141625510932476205^%^3Bexp-1650810387024^$_ga:3709217651.1635946456^$original_v_id:017ce601df9f0014c6961521a19605072001206a00bd0-polopoly^$dc_visit:66^$last_bc:100266130^$ses_id:1643034379252^%^3Bexp-session^$_pn:3^%^3Bexp-session^$adobe_mcid:67643106713851798281164191083147300093^%^3Bexp-session^$aa_vid:307AE6471406DA2D-4000119A8E36CC44^%^3Bexp-session^$appnexus_sync_session:1643034379252^%^3Bexp-session^$_prevpage:nl-sports.unibet.be^%^3A^%^3A^%^3Adesktop^%^3Abetting^%^3Asports^%^3Afilter^%^3Afootball^%^3Abelgium^%^3Ajupiler_pro_league^%^3Bexp-session^$_prevnew_page_name:^%^3Abetting^%^3Asports^%^3Afilter^%^3Afootball^%^3Abelgium^%^3Ajupiler_pro_league^%^3Bexp-session^$_prevnew_full_url:https^%^3A^%^2F^%^2Fnl-sports.unibet.be^%^2Fbetting^%^2Fsports^%^2Ffilter^%^2Ffootball^%^2Fbelgium^%^2Fjupiler_pro_league^%^3Bexp-session^$dc_event:3^%^3Bexp-session\" ^
  --compressed"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: That's not a URL, it's a (Windows-only) curl command line. Only Windows uses `^` as a line continuation or quoting character; and Python multi-line strings should use triple quotes to begin and end them.

Answer (score -2):

This is not a valid Python (3.6 at least) string.
Following page generates valid Python 3.6 code:
https://hoppscotch.io

[image]

Hope this syntax colouring helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32084829)